# Redirecionamento Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url

Estou a ter o seguinte cenário...Possuo um blog que ao clicar em um link é redirecionado para uma página em Vue.js. Todavia quando ele é redirecionado a página quebra e retorna o error 404. 
Qualquer / apos a raiz do site em Vue.js esta quebrando.

Ex: advogadosbrasil.com entra normalmente e também redirecionado do blog vem normal. Quando colocando no modo advogadosbrasil.com/contato é retornado o erro 404.

obs: Entrando nas url de dentro do site elas são apresentadas normalmente.

meu arquivo vue.config.js esta da seguinte forma:

```js
module.exports = {
       baseUrl: '/'
}
```

Alguém ja passou por esse problema ou sabe a solução??

Comment: Se a solução do seu problema foi resposta abaixo aceite como resposta da sua pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

De acordo com a [Documentação](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl), `baseUrl` está depreciado desde a versão 3.3 do VueJS, sendo necessário o uso do `publicPath`.

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/',
}
```

Comment: estou tendo que fazer umas alterações que o cliente pediu, porem não desenvolvi em Vue.js..o senhor diz fazer algo assim:

module.exports = {
       publicPath: '/'
}

Comment: Nao tive muita base na documentação

Comment: seria isso mesmo Betini, atualizei a resposta com o exemplo.

Comment: foi, obrigado =]

Comment: magina, fico feliz que funcionou ;)